# How to convert an integer value to boolean in delphi

Tags: delphi, type-conversion, dbgrid

I have a database field value, which is an integer like 0 and 1. Is it possible to convert 
this integer values to Boolean while loading the data in to a DB Grid. I'm expecting without condition checking, like direct typecasting.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know about databases, but the question in the title is very easy. If `i: integer` then `i = 1` is a boolean.

Comment: @Andreas: `i <> 0` is probably a bit more idiomatic and robust.

Comment: @Ulrich: You are absolutely right.

Comment: AFAIK you can not do this. boolean type has 2 possible values, and integer much much more possible values. So, NO you can not.

Comment: @RBA: Converting is allowed to loose information (converting a double to an integer is the same situation) so there's no reason you cannot convert an integer to a boolean.

Comment: @Smasher - indeed, it's true.... anyway, I would not design an app + dbb where a field is of type integer and I manipulate it like a boolean value. IMHO this is a no-no

Comment: @RBA - MySQL, for example, does not have a "boolean" type (it uses `tinyint(1)` to store truth values.) So long as semantics are the same, you are safe using `if (val <> 0) then true else false` or something like that.

Comment: What is the purpose of the conversion?

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to convert Integer to Boolean.
you can implement a function like this

```
function IntToBool(const AnInt: Integer): Boolean;
begin
   if AnInt = 0 then Result := False
                else Result := True;     
end;
```

Comment: Or simpler: `Result := AnInt <> 0;` Alternatively `Result := LongBool(AnInt);`

Answer (score 3):

I guess that you want to show a database field in DBGrid as a CheckBox. If so, read [article by Zarko Gajic](http://delphi.about.com/od/usedbvcl/l/aa082003a.htm). It is about Boolean fields, but you can easily modify the code for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple solution to your problem would probably be to use a boolean calcfield.

If you need to edit it from the DBGrid, it gets a little bit more tricky (But still possible).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the words "True" and "False" in DBGrid, you should use OnGetText event of **Field** like this :

```
procedure TMyForm.MyDataSetFieldGetText(Sender: TField;
  var Text: string; DisplayText: Boolean);
begin
 case Sender.AsInteger of
  0 : Text := 'False';
  1 : Text := 'True';
 else
  Text := '-';
 end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this sample function here:

```
 function IntToBooleanStr(AInteger: Integer): string;
 begin
   case AInteger of
     0:begin
         Result := 'False';
       end;
     1:begin
         Result := 'True';
       end 
       else
           Result := 'False';
   end;
 end;
```

that's all and you can use it inside the combobox onChange Event for FILTERING Some Logical Data that has the boolean values inside. 
like here:

```
procedure TFrm_Books.ComBox_AvailableFilterChange(Sender: TObject);
begin   
   Table_Book.Filtered := False;
   Table_Book.FilterOptions := [foCaseInsensitive];
   Table_Book.Filter := '';
   Table_Book.Filter := 'Available = ' + IntToBooleanStr(ComBox_AvailableFilter.ItemIndex);
   Table_Book.Filtered := True;
end;
```

and here is the DFM Code for this combobox:

```
object ComBox_AvailableFilter: TComboBox
  Left = 336
  Top = 120
  Width = 193
  Height = 21
  ItemHeight = 13
  Items.Strings = (
    'Not Available'
    'Available')
  TabOrder = 0
end
```

i hope this function resolve your question Above.